# kubectl terminal command not working from crontab , how to fix?

Tags: python, cron, kubernetes, kubectl

I have below small python script

```
import os
os.system('kubectl get pods --context students-cmn')
```

when i run this command manually from terminal it is working , no issue , so i configured it to run as a cron job , but when cron job triggered getting below error

```
sh: kubectl: command not found
```

why , when the cronjob triggered , kubectl not working ?

can anyone please help

Comment: Well, which system are you using?

Comment: am using mac os sierra

Comment: everything whatever i did for this on mac os sierra

Comment: you need to give a full path of `kubectl` like `/usr/bin/kubectl` or something like that, wherever its path is. Also please check the user which run the cron job has proper access to `kubectl`.

Comment: thanks @user2906838 , it worked , i used complete path now .

Answer (score 10):

First of all, I imagine you are planning on adding code to your python script and that that is why you use python. I assume you used the crontab of the user that can run the command.

When you execute a command in `cron` you must specify the full path to the command. To find the full path to `kubectl`, you issue the following in Terminal:

```
which kubectl
```

It will print the full path.

Then, you edit your script (assuming the full path is "/opt/Kubernetes/bin"):

```
import os
os.system('/opt/Kubernetes/bin/kubectl get pods --context students-cmn')
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the same issue when i tried to execute "kubectl" command into .sh/py file from CentOS 7 with cron.
i could run script .sh/.py file manually and the output was fine. 
when i tried to set cron job with script, "kubectl" command could not be executed.
it didnot generate any logs for cron events.
if you dont mind, please support me.

`crontab : * * * * * python /home/sanglv/kube-status.py >> /tmp/status.txt`

`kube-status.py file :`
`#!/usr/bin/env python`
`#ls command`
`import os`
`os.system('/usr/bin/kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --kubeconfig="/root/.kube/config"')`

Comment: I have the same problem, to understand what is happening you need to print both dhe stdout and stderr doing something like

`python script.py > stdout.log 2> stderr.log`

I had this problem and the answer is basically, crontab cant find aws-iam-authenticator because its env_vars are different from yours. The solution is simply to export the PATH variable you have and add it in the script, with it added then all should work fine.

Final script:
```PATH=/home/ubuntu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin```

Comment: For me it was the `PATH` issue as @LucasScoppio suggested. Thanks @LucasScoppio